# Class not binding to ui-view before ng-enter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

To achieve different animations between states - I'm applying a class to the ui-view depending on the current state:

```
<div ng-class="currentClass.current.name" ui-view></div>
```

This works, however - **initially** when the view enters, it appears ng-enter is applied before the class in `currentClass.current.name` has been bound, so my animation gets ignored:

```
.slide-right.ng-enter {
  z-index: 100;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I can apply animations to `ng-leave` - because the `currentClass.current.name` has been applied prior to this.

See [plunker code for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3QjBzRu5VjOzK7czn71e?p=preview). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> CSS classes managed by ng-class conflict with ALL ui-view animations.

So, the issue is in this line

```
<section ui-view ng-class="stateClass"></section>
```

Unfortunately, ng-class is not compatible with ui-view. Here's the complete [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/866).

So you can use `class="{{stateClass}}"` with ui-view.

```
<section ui-view class="{{stateClass}}"></section>
```

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ymSGZdHZXSvoXTTDmFnr?p=preview)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As ng-class doesn't supported by ui-view you could try `ng-attr-class` which will set the attribute value when the interpolation directive gets parsed.

Use `ng-attr-class="{{stateClass}}"` for setting class attribute

**Markup**

```
<div class="row">
    <section ui-view ng-attr-class="{{stateClass}}"></section>
</div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3QjBzRu5VjOzK7czn71e?p=preview)